# MVC web site ask to store cookies form "login.live.com"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I change my browser setting to prompt permission whenever a site request to store cookie. Then I debug the project and was prompted to allow cookies form ‘login.live.com’ (as the figure following figure shows).

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCSMQ.png)

At the time code doesn’t reach to the ‘Application_Start()’ method.
I hosted my site in IIS too, but nothing deference.

1. Could anyone please explain me that behavior, why this happening?
2. And is there any possibility to avoid that request or call? (By not
   disabling the prompt by the browser.)

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: How is authentication set up in your site?

Comment: @HansKesting No authentication has used.